# Prepared statement in PHP with MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, session, prepared-statement, sha1

I am currently doing a project regarding SQL injection and I have to provide a countermeasure to it. I have been trying to use the prepared statement as my countermeasure. But currently my after attempting for a few hours, I am not able to do it. It keeps giving me a plain white screen on my page which is suppose to redirect it to another page or show a message

Here are the codes
doLogin page:

```
<?php
session_start();
require('dbFunction.php');
$username = $_POST['form-username'];
$password = SHA1($_POST['form-password']);
$msg = "";

$stmt = $link -> prepare("SELECT * FROM User WHERE Email = ? AND Password = ?");
$stmt -> bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
$stmt -> execute();

if($stmt -> get_result() -> num_rows > 0) {
$row = $stmt-> get_result() ->fetch_assoc();
$_SESSION['email'] = $row['Email'];
$_SESSION['userId'] = $row['UserId'];
$_SESSION['role'] = $row['role'];
$_SESSION['First_name'] = $row['First_name'];
header("location:index.php");
}
else{
$msg .= "Wrong user combination.";
}

$stmt -> close();
$link -> close();

include "navbar.php";
echo $msg;
echo error_get_last();

?>
```

Here is the code for my database connection:

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_password = "P@$\$w0rd";
$db_name = "mydb";
$link = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_password,$db_name);

if(!$link){
die(mysqli_error($link));
}
```

Comment: You are simply missing an `echo` or `prinf` statement in your `else` condition.

Comment: In your $stmt, do you receive any data? I mean do you get loggedIn?

Comment: add `echo $msg;` in your `else` statement.

Comment: Nope, I didn't get logged in. Which I think means I didn't receive any data. @Nagesh Katna

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_password = "P@$\$w0rd";
$db_name = "mydb";
$link = new mysqli($db_host,$db_username,$db_password,$db_name);

if ($link->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Comment: tried it but I am still facing the same white screen.

Comment: I can't see how this answer received so many upvotes, IMHO. All that was done here, was used the correct error handling on the connection, which should have IMHO have been said in comments. It does not solve the question. Saying *"Try using..."* is just that; a comment.

Comment: Plus, this `"P@$\$w0rd";` given as shown, *will* fail for a few reasons.